# Django - Show list datetime values in template

Tags: django, datetime, templates

I have below code which outputs datetime values as shown below:

```
available_hours = [hour for hour in hours_between if hour not in reserved_times]
    print(available_hours)

[datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 19, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 20, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 8, 21, 0)]
```

I render them in the template like:

```
{{ available_hours }}
```

and i got all above datetime values.

How can i change the format so i can show them like Mon 12 2021, 21:00?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <p>
  available hours:
  {% for my_time in available_hours %}

 {{ my_time|date:"M d Y, H:i" }}

 {% endfor %}
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. I tried but nothing is displayed.

Comment: Thank you it's fine. BTW I do not know if it is right to post it here but since i know you have helped me on other posts as well, and of course if you have the time, could you please have a quick look on this post also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274056/django-find-reserved-times. Is the only part left to finish my project and i have stuck.